# Find if two variables are in the same line

Tags: python, string

I have two lists of IPs. I want to validate that for each pair both exists on the same line in a file: `ips_template.txt`. If either IP doesn't exists in the file `ips_template.txt` or they are not a "pair" - print the mismatch. In `bash` I would just pipe two `grep`, looking for something with same result.

```
firstIPs = re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", firststring)
secondIPs = re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", secondstring)

if firstIPs or secondIPs :
    print 'one of the lists didn\'t had IPs.'
    sys.exit(2)
if len(firstIPs ) != len(secondIPs ):
    print 'IPs len mismatch'
    sys.exit(2)

for old, new in zip(firstIPs , secondIPs ):
# bash example to search in the file ips_template.txt
# if [ `cat ips_template.txt | grep old | grep new | wc -l` -gt 0 ]
#    echo 'match'
# else
#    echo ips not matched or missing
# fi
```

`ips_template.txt` exmaple:

```
hostname 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 hostname_type
hostname2 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 hostname_type2
```

`firststring` and `secondstring` can be different formats each run and some are unknown. That is why I rip only the IPs from them with the assumptions that the order of the IPs/hosts are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search `ips_template.txt` for the IP's I did the following:

```py
with open("ips_template.txt", "r") as ips_template_file:
    ips_template = ips_template_file.readlines()

for old, new in zip(firstIPs , secondIPs ):
    missing = True
    pattern = r"%s\s*%s" % (old, new)

    for line in ips_template:
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            print("matched %s %s" % (old, new))
            missing = False
            break

    if missing:
        print("missing %s %s" % (old, new))
```

Also when checking if the lists even have IP's in them I inserted two `not`'s:

```py
if not firstIPs or not secondIPs:
```

because else it said only "one of the lists didn't had IPs." when at least one of them contained IP's.

---

My complete code I worked with is:

```py
import re
import sys

firststring = "1.1.1.1\n1.1.1.1\n3.3.3.3\n2.2.2.2"
secondstring = "1.1.1.1\n2.2.2.2\n not an IP adress\n2.2.2.2\n4.4.4.4"

firstIPs = re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", firststring)
secondIPs = re.findall(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", secondstring)

if not firstIPs or not secondIPs :
    print('one of the lists didn\'t had IPs.')
    sys.exit(2)
if len(firstIPs ) != len(secondIPs ):
    print('IPs len mismatch')
    sys.exit(2)

with open("ips_template.txt", "r") as ips_template_file:
    ips_template = ips_template_file.readlines()

for old, new in zip(firstIPs , secondIPs ):
    missing = True
    pattern = r"%s\s*%s" % (old, new)

    for line in ips_template:
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            print("matched %s %s" % (old, new))
            missing = False
            break

    if missing:
        print("missing %s %s" % (old, new))
```

`ips_template.txt` looked like this:

```py
hostname 1.1.1.1    1.1.1.1 hostname_type
hostname2 3.3.3.3  2.2.2.2 hostname_type2
hostname3 2.2.2.2 2.2.2.2 hostname_type3
```

And the output of my code is:

```py
matched 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.1
missing 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
matched 3.3.3.3 2.2.2.2
missing 2.2.2.2 4.4.4.4
```

Comment: Hi, what you are missing is that I want to search those IPs in single line in an additional file: `ips_template.txt`. Look at the bash `if` comment.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide an example of `ips_template.txt`? Also helpful would be examples of `firststring` and `laststring` and the expected output of the code.  Then I can improve my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it is useful now. If not please provide more details about the behaviour you expect and/or more detailed examples.

Comment: Can you adjust the `" ".join([old, new])` to be any amount of spaces/tabs as long as they are in the same line?

Comment: Ok I did ;) If you change the format of your `ips_template.txt` you can simply change the `pattern` to match your new format. You can learn more about regular expressions in Python here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html